# не получается вернуть значение функции

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function names() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/file.php',
        data: 'name=lalala',
        success: function(text){
            //допустим text равен: игорь, делаю так:
            return text;
        }
    });
}

var name = names();
```

как сделать так, чтобы переменная name была равна "игорь"? сейчас выводит `undefined?`, если с `return`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> -- Угадай, кто лучший в мире подносчик тефтелей?
>
> -- Ты, Карлсон?

Так как меня зовут "Игорь", я, без ложной скромности, смогу дать лучший ответ на этот вопрос.

Обработчик `success` асинхронного `ajax` запроса выполняется асинхронно. Значение переменной `name` должно быть присвоено (и использовано) не раньше, чем вызовется код внутри этого `success`.

```
var name;

function names() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/file.php',
    data: 'name=lalala',
    success: function(text){
    //допустим text равен: игорь, делаю так:
      name = text;
    }
  });
}
```